# How do we know what control to specify in an optimal control problem?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, optimal-control

**My question is based on the following passage in Liberzon's "calculus of variations and optimal control theory". I have added it to clarify the context of my question:**

---

[image]

---

### My question is:

Liberzon chooses the definitions of the control variables $u_1:=\frac {\dot x}{\sqrt y}$ and $u_2:=\frac {\dot y}{\sqrt y}$.

- **Firstly**, I don't intuitively see what the meaning of $u_1$ and $u_2$ are, conceptually.
- **More importantly**, How do we know that this is the correct choice? Why couldn't I have chosen some other definition? How does this definition help us solve the problem?

---

.

### Edit: Here is some context as requested by @Ian:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think we need some of the prior context, especially the cost functional.

Comment: @Ian, I've added the entire problem referred to. I hope it's not too much, but I didn't know what to copy more specifically without it being confusing.

Comment: OK, now rewrite $J$ as an integral $dt$ where $x=x(t),y=y(t)$. I think you will see the connection to these $u_1,u_2$ then.